# Need a faster way in Powershell to merge large arrays in a single 2-dimensional array

Tags: arrays, powershell, merge, datatable

I am facing a situation, where I need a very fast method to merge multiple large arrays via Powershell.
Originally the data are coming from a json-input, but to explain my challenge here is a small code-snippet that creates a similar situation:

```
$columnCount = 10 # this number is NOT fixed!
$rowCount = 10KB
$allData = @()
$titles = @()

# create sample input data for the scenario that I need to solve:
foreach($i in 1..$columnCount) {
    $titles += "Column$i"
    $columnData = ,"$i" * $rowCount
    $alldata += ,$columnData
}
```

Now I need a fast way to merge this 10 one-dimensional arrays with their data per column into a single 2-dimensional array with correct column titles.

I started with this code:

```
$t = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()

$result = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
$columnMaxId = $columnCount-1
$rowMaxId = $allData[0].count-1
foreach($row in 0..$rowMaxId) {
    $line = [PsObject]::new()
    foreach($column in 0..$columnMaxId) {
        $line | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $titles[$column] -Value $allData[$column][$row]
    }
    $null = $result.Add($line)
}

$t.Stop()
$t.Elapsed.TotalSeconds
```

The runtime was 12,2429499 seconds with the above demo data.
Because I had to run this kind of task very frequently and the real data are sometimes even larger and had up to 30 columns this solution is not fast enough. How can I speed this up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using datatables for the above task. Adding rows in a datatable allows to pass an array of values per row and that way I can handle the dynamic length of each row. Here my code:

```
$t = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()

$table = [System.Data.Datatable]::new()
foreach($title in $titles) {[void]$table.Columns.Add($title)}
$columnMaxId = $columnCount-1
foreach($row in 0..($rowCount-1)){
    $dataRow = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
    foreach($column in 0..$columnMaxId){
        [void]$dataRow.Add($allData[$column][$row])
    }
    [void]$table.Rows.Add([array]$dataRow)
}

$t.Stop()
$t.Elapsed.TotalSeconds
```

The runtime for the above demo-input is now 0,3300486 seconds.